# twilio voice javascript typescript version

Tags: twilio

Hi I just want to know if there is already a typescript version of twilio.js that I can use now? Hope someone can share a definitely type would be ok for now. I found a node twilio @types in npm but I cannot used it because I am using the javascript version of twilio. This is for voice btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Client is written in JavaScript and I don't believe that anyone has created external types for it yet.

Comment: part of the issue is that the repo (github.com/twilio/twilio-client.js) is not open source, no one wants to read through babel transpiled code to make third party typings... is there any way for the source code to be released?

Comment: I don’t believe there’s any intention to release the source at the moment.

Comment: well, through the babel transpiled code I go! When I finish I intend to release to definitelytyped so TS devs can get typings for the client, if you are interested I can let you guys know when that happens with an email or something

Comment: Good luck! Do let me know when you publish, it would be great to share! You can get me at philnash@twilio.com.